# I was asked to make a program in python to check whether a sorting algorithm is stable or not. Need some help regarding that

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

So I decided to approach this problem by creating another array (lets say arraycount) with the same length of the input array(lets say arraynumber) which is to be sorted. For the program to really check the stability of the sorting function, I decided to use test cases of integer array of repeated occurrences eg `arraynumber = {10,8,7,8,2,2,2,1,6}`. I then use a function to calculate the occurrences of the number in the array and store them in the `arraycount[]` which will result as `arraycount={1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,1}`.
Naturally after sorting in increasing order they become `arraynumber={1,2,2,2,6,7,8,8,10}` and the result of the arraycount decides that its stable or not. Hence if its stable `arraycount={1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2,1}` otherwise it won't be same.
This is the code I have been working on. Help and feedback is appreciated. Main function and input is not taken yet. I will take another array copy of the original arraycount which will be compared afterward to check if it's retained the original position. Sorry if I made any trivial mistakes. Thank you.

```
def merge(arr1, l, m, r,arr2): 
    n1 = m - l + 1
    n2 = r- m 

    # create temp arrays 
    L = [0] * (n1) 
    R = [0] * (n2) 

    # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] 
    for i in range(0 , n1): 
        L[i] = arr1[l + i] 

    for j in range(0 , n2): 
        R[j] = arr1[m + 1 + j] 

    # Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r] 
    i = 0     # Initial index of first subarray 
    j = 0     # Initial index of second subarray 
    k = l     # Initial index of merged subarray 

    while i < n1 and j < n2 : 
        if L[i] <= R[j]: 
            arr1[k] = L[i]
            arr2[k]=L[i]
            i += 1
        else: 
            arr1[k] = R[j]
            arr2[k]=R[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    # Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
    # are any 
    while i < n1: 
        arr1[k] = L[i]
        arr2[k]=L[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    # Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
    # are any 
    while j < n2: 
        arr1[k] = R[j]
        arr2[k]=R[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

# l is for left index and r is right index of the 
# sub-array of arr to be sorted 
def mergeSort(arr1,l,r,arr2): 
    if l < r: 

        # Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for 
        # large l and h 
        m = (l+(r-1))/2

        # Sort first and second halves 
        mergeSort(arr1, l, m,arr2) 
        mergeSort(arr1, m+1, r,arr2) 
        merge(arr1, l, m, r,arr2)


# This function takes last element as pivot, places 
# the pivot element at its correct position in sorted 
# array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot) 
# to left of pivot and all greater elements to right 
# of pivot 
def partition(arr1,low,high,arr2): 
    i = ( low-1 )         # index of smaller element 
    pivot = arr1[high]     # pivot 

    for j in range(low , high): 

        # If current element is smaller than or 
        # equal to pivot 
        if   arr1[j] <= pivot: 

            # increment index of smaller element 
            i = i+1 
            arr1[i],arr1[j] = arr1[j],arr1[i]
            arr2[i],arr2[j]=arr2[j],arr2[i]

    arr1[i+1],arr1[high] = arr1[high],arr1[i+1]
    arr2[i+1],arr2[high]=arr2[high],arr2[i+1]
    return ( i+1 ) 

# The main function that implements QuickSort 
# arr1[] --> Array to be sorted,
# arr2[] --> Second Array of the count to be sorted along with first array
# low  --> Starting index, 
# high  --> Ending index 

# Function to do Quick sort 
def quickSort(arr1,low,high,arr2): 
    if low < high: 

        # pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now 
        # at right place 
        pi = partition(arr1,low,high,arr2) 

        # Separately sort elements before 
        # partition and after partition 
        quickSort(arr1, low, pi-1,arr2) 
        quickSort(arr1, pi+1, high,arr2)


def countArray(arr1,arr2):
i=0,j=1,k=0
    while i<range(len(arr1[])):

        while j<range(len(arr1[])):
            if arr1[i]==arr1[j]:
                arr2[i]=k+1
            j=j+1
            k=0
        i=i+1

arraylist=[]        
arraycount=[]
def isStable(arr1,arr2):
    k=0
    while i < range(len(arr1[])):
        if arr[i]==arr2[i]:
           k=k+1
        i=i+1

    if k==len(arr2):
        print("Stable sort")
    else:
        print("Unstable sort")
```

Comment: Hi. If I understand correctly, your code works fine and you're looking for feedback? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate.

Comment: Wikipedia: "stable sorting algorithms maintain the relative order of records with equal keys (i.e. values). That is, a sorting algorithm is stable if whenever there are two records R and S with the same key and with R appearing before S in the original list, R will appear before S in the sorted list". If that is the same meaning of stable as you are using, with integers in the list how can you actually tell that any particular sequence of (say) 2s in the input is in fact __the same__ sequence of 2s in the output, because the entries (integers) are indistinguishable?

Comment: I don't know if a program can be used to prove a sort is stable, only to find a case that shows that a sort is unstable. To test for a non-stable sort, data to be sorted needs to include something to indicate the original order of an element that is not included when comparing elements.  You could sort an array of pairs of {random number, index}, by only comparing the random number part. A 32 bit integer could be composed of a (16 bit random number << 16) + (index), and only compare the upper 16 bits.